# How to combine two jQuery codes?

Tags: jquery

I have two code blocks, they just have a little difference, But I have no idea how to combine them.

code A:

```
$("ul.program.tab-menu li", ".program.tab-container").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this), 
        _clickTab = $this.find('a').attr('href');
    window.location.hash = _clickTab;
    $this.addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(_clickTab).stop(false, true).fadeIn().siblings().hide();
    return false;
}).find('a').focus(function(){
    this.blur();
});
```

code B:

```
$("ul.tab-menu li", ".tab-container").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this), 
        _clickTab = $this.find('a').attr('href');
    $this.addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(_clickTab).stop(false, true).fadeIn().siblings().hide();
    return false;
}).find('a').focus(function(){
    this.blur();
});
```

Differences:

1. class - `program.tab-menu` and `tab-menu`
2. there are `location.hash` in code A, but code B isn't.

Comment: What do you want to achieve using the script?

Comment: @PiotrUchman `tab-menu` click won't change url.hash, but `program-menu` click will add hash tag after url.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, but it is just guessing, what you are looking for is:

```
$("ul.tab-menu li", ".tab-container").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this), 
        _clickTab = $this.find('a').attr('href');
    window.location.hash = _clickTab;
    $this.addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(_clickTab).stop(false, true).fadeIn().siblings().hide();
    return false;
}).find('a').focus(function(){
this.blur();
});
```

Comment: only `.program.tab-menu` click have `window.location.hash` effect , this code just have tab-menu, so maybe not work me, but very thanks :)